# append filename with date

Tags: r, date, csv

I successfully managed to export my data to a `.csv` file with my counting variable `i` as file name and would like to add the `date()` to my file name to have a unique identifier and the files wont get over written when running the code multiple times.
First I thought the `space` in `date()` wont allow me to use it and I replaced the `spaces` with an `_` but it still denies permission.

`date = date()
 View(date)
 date2 = gsub(" ", "_",date)
 write.csv(a, file=paste0("I:/C14Data/QualityControl/Johannes/", i, "_", date2, ".csv"))`

I'm sure there is a simple solution to it but I could not find it!!
Thanks a lot in advance. Johannes

Comment: How about `:`'s? :-) *`[1] "Tue Aug  5 23:45:10 2014"`*

Comment: @`Simon O'Hanlon` Where do you want me to put the `colon`?

Comment: `:` are not valid in filenames, except after the drive letter (on windows). `date()` outputs a character string with `:`'s in it. You need to remove them, e.g. `date <- gsub( ":" , "-" , date() )`

Comment: So you might prefer something like `strftime(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` rather than transforming `date()` character values. That way you can specify the format string how ever you like. `strftime` has many formatting options.

Comment: My code looks like that now and it works as I want it: `date = gsub(":","-",Sys.time())
  date = gsub(" ","_",date)
  View(date)
  write.csv(a, file=paste0("I:/C14Data/QualityControl/Johannes/", i, "_", date, " (yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss).csv"))` And the output looks like: `1_2014-08-06_11-16-39 (yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss).csv`

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon You should post an answer so you get credit ;) Cheers, bud

Comment: @Reed feel free. :-) MrFlick's answer is more useful and flexible anyway.

Comment: `Sys.Date()` for date with "-" separators, no white space. (Date only, no time)

Comment: `@Dale`, Thanks for your suggestion, but I do like to have the time in the filename as well, just because if you run your code multiple times a day then the previously created files wont be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I wrote a quick utility that will take care of this for you. It appends a date onto a string, using default characters that should be valid for a filename (but you can specify others if you chose). It can be found [here](https://github.com/adam-m-mcelhinney/helpRFunctions/blob/master/R/date.time.append.r) or below.

```
date.time.append <- function(str, sep = '_', date.format ="%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S") {
stopifnot(is.character(str))
return(paste(str, format(Sys.time(), date.format), sep = sep))  
}
```